# client/server socket in c# can't connect to each other on LAN

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, networking, client-server

The client/server that I tried works fine with localhost but when I try to do it on another computer - One for the server, One for the client - There's an error saying No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 192.168.0.101:8. Can somebody help me about this matter? I already tried to turn off the firewalls on both of the computers.

The code of the program is below:

**Server Side - Main Code**

```
namespace Multiple_Connection_Server
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {
        Listener listener;
        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            label3.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
            listener = new Listener(8);
            listener.SocketAccepted += new Listener.SocketAcceptedHandler(listener_SocketAccepted);
            Load += new EventHandler(Main_Load);
        }

    void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listener.Start();
    }

    void listener_SocketAccepted(System.Net.Sockets.Socket e)
    {
        Client client = new Client(e);
        client.Received += new Client.ClientReceivedHandler(client_Received);
        client.Disconnected += new Client.ClientDisconnectedHandler(client_Disconnected);

        Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            listEndpoint.Items.Add(client.Endpoint.ToString());
            ListViewItem i = new ListViewItem();
            i.Text = client.Endpoint.ToString();
            i.SubItems.Add(client.ID);
            i.SubItems.Add("XX");
            i.SubItems.Add("XX");
            i.Tag = client;
            lstClient.Items.Add(i);
        });
    }

    void client_Received(Client sender, byte[] data)
    {
        string input = Encoding.Default.GetString(data);
        try
        {
            Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < lstClient.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    Client client = lstClient.Items[i].Tag as Client;

                    if (client.ID == sender.ID)
                    {
                        lstClient.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text = Encoding.Default.GetString(data);
                        lstClient.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                        listChat.Items.Add("Message: " + input);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });

            using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Windows\InformationLogs.txt", true))
            {
                streamWriter.WriteLine("[Date]: " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + " --- [Message Log]: " + input);

            }
        }

        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message);
        }
    }

    void client_Disconnected(Client sender)
    {
        Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < lstClient.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                Client client = lstClient.Items[i].Tag as Client;

                if (client.ID == sender.ID)
                {
                    lstClient.Items.RemoveAt(i);
                    listEndpoint.Items.RemoveAt(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

---

**Server Side - Listener Class**

```
namespace Multiple_Connection_Server
{
    class Listener
    {
        Socket s;

    public bool Listening
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public int Port
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public Listener(int port)
    {
        Port = port;
        s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        if (Listening)
            return;

        s.Bind(new IPEndPoint(0, Port));
        s.Listen(0);

        s.BeginAccept(callback, null);
        Listening = true;
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        if (!Listening)
            return;

        s.Close();
        s.Dispose();
        s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    }

    void callback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket s = this.s.EndAccept(ar);

            if (SocketAccepted != null)
            {
                SocketAccepted(s);
            }

            this.s.BeginAccept(callback, null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    public delegate void SocketAcceptedHandler(Socket e);
    public event SocketAcceptedHandler SocketAccepted;
}
```

}

---

**Server Side - Client Code**

```
namespace Multiple_Connection_Server
{
    class Client
    {
        public string ID
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

    public IPEndPoint Endpoint
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    Socket sck;
    public Client(Socket accepted)
    {
        sck = accepted;
        ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        Endpoint = (IPEndPoint)sck.RemoteEndPoint;
        sck.BeginReceive(new byte[] { 0 }, 0, 0, 0, callback, null);
    }

    void callback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            sck.EndReceive(ar);

            byte[] buf = new byte[8192];

            int rec = sck.Receive(buf, buf.Length, 0);

            if (rec < buf.Length)
            {
                Array.Resize<byte>(ref buf, rec);
            }

            if (Received != null)
            {
                Received(this, buf);
            }

            sck.BeginReceive(new byte[] { 0 }, 0, 0, 0, callback, null);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Close();

            if (Disconnected != null)
            {
                Disconnected(this);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        sck.Close();
        sck.Dispose();
    }

    public delegate void ClientReceivedHandler(Client sender, byte[] data);
    public delegate void ClientDisconnectedHandler(Client sender);

    public event ClientReceivedHandler Received;
    public event ClientDisconnectedHandler Disconnected;
}
```

}

---

**Client Side - Main Code**

```
namespace Multiple_Connection_Client
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {
        Socket sck;
        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        }

    private void btnConnect_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            sck.Connect(txtBoxIPAdd.Text, 8);
            MessageBox.Show("Connected");
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void btnSend_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int s = sck.Send(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(txtMesg.Text));
            listBox1.Items.Add("Message: " + txtMesg.Text);
            txtMesg.Text = "";
            if (s > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Data Sent");
            }
        }

        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
        }
    }

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your computers are on a WiFi network...? or there is a router b/w your client and server?

Comment: Yes, I do have a router and both of my computers can ping each other

Comment: Then I think you need to configure your router for forwarding ports to your server. Especially Port 8

Comment: Have you tried to run the client and server on the same machine just to make sure the network is not the problem?

Comment: @Tariq What if I'll try it without a router? How will that work?

Comment: @Doktorn Yeah, I tried that already and it works fine .. It can connect and receive the message

Comment: If both your client and server are directly connected to the internet (no user router in between) then you only need to know your internet IP. But if your server is connected to a user router (D-link, linksys etc) then you need to configure port forwarding on it.

Comment: @Tariq I already tried connecting it and it always says "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it <my IP add - 192.168.1.101:8>" when I click the connect button on the other PC which is the client

Comment: See, one reason for this problem can be that server is not listening on port 8. Are you sure that server's ip address is 192.168.1.101? you can confirm it by executing command `ipconfig`. Have you tried to forward ports on your router since some router need port forwarding even on LAN.

Comment: @Tariq The problem is not the port 8 .. I just figured out that I'm inputting the client's IP instead of the ip of the server .. Thanks for the help by the way .. It's now working fine no need to forward ports

Answer (score 0):

Port numbers below 1024 are generally reserved and require special security.  Try using a higher port number.